# SQL Update - Everything inside ()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column of data containing a string with the following format:

```
blablablabla(XYZ)
```

and I would like to discard everything outside the () - and the parenthesis themselves - and to set update that field with the value inside the (). This implies that, in this particular case, the "blablabla" would be discarded and that entry would only contain XYZ.

I know that I have to use SQL UPDATE, but i'm not sure on how to build the where condition properly.

Many thanks,
Hal

EDIT: i forgot to say that it was in SQL Server 2008.
Thank you all for your answers, they all worked (i tested). Too bad i can't mark all as correct. I'm really amazed, the answers were all so quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that there is *exactly one* pair of *correctly nested* parentheses (and is T-SQL syntax):

```
DECLARE @bla VARCHAR(50)
SET @bla = 'blablablabla(XYZ)asdsdsad'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
         @bla, 
         CHARINDEX('(', @bla) + 1, 
         CHARINDEX(')', @bla) - CHARINDEX('(', @bla) - 1
       )
```

Yields:

```
'XYZ'
```

---

EDIT: This checks for various ill-formatted strings and could be used in a WHERE clause (e.g. `WHERE ... <> 'no match'`):

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      /* check for '(' and ')' */
      CHARINDEX('(', @bla) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(')', @bla) > CHARINDEX('(', @bla)
      /* check for 'bla(bla(XYZ)bla' */
      AND CHARINDEX('(', @bla, CHARINDEX('(', @bla) + 1) = 0
      /* check for 'bla(XYZ)bla)bla' */
      AND CHARINDEX(')', @bla, CHARINDEX(')', @bla) + 1) = 0
    THEN SUBSTRING(@bla, 
          CHARINDEX('(', @bla) + 1, 
          CHARINDEX(')', @bla) - CHARINDEX('(', @bla) - 1
        ) 
    ELSE 'no match'
  END
```

Comment: Actually , won't this give error if the data does not have parenthesis?

Comment: That's why I included the "assumes exactly one pair" part. :-)

Answer (score 5):

In `MySQL`:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     column = SUBSTRING(column, INSTR(column, '(') + 1, INSTR(column, ')') - INSTR(column, '(') - 1)
WHERE   column RLIKE ('\\(.*\\)')
```

Comment: Might want to add WHERE column LIKE '%(%)%', so you don't try to update rows that don't match the pattern

Comment: I forgot to say that it was in SQL Server 2008.
Thank you for you solution, i gave +1

Answer (score 3):

MSSQL Solution. The function you're looking for is CharIndex
Simple table called test containing one column called [name]

Code To Insert Entries

```
INSERT INTO TEST (name) VALUES ('SomeString(test1)')
INSERT INTO TEST (name) VALUES ('test2')
INSERT INTO TEST (name) VALUES ('SomeOtherString(test3)')
INSERT INTO TEST (name) VALUES ('test4')
```

SQL Code to Find The Relevant Entries

```
SELECT *, 
    charindex('(', name), 
    charindex(')', name),
    substring(
        name,
        charindex('(', name) + 1,
        charindex(')', name) - charindex('(', name) - 1
    )
FROM 
    TEST 
WHERE 
    name like '%(%)%'
```

SQL Code to update entries

```
UPDATE 
    TEST
SET
    name = substring(
        name,
        charindex('(', name) + 1,
        charindex(')', name) - charindex('(', name) - 1
    )
WHERE
    name like '%(%)%'
```

Comment: Heh, I managed to copy your solution before you even posted it. :-P

Comment: heh! that's what I get for actually writing in Mngt Studio instead of off the top of my head :)

Comment: Well, actually I wrote up mine in SSMS as well, not getting the string index calculations right with sub-string functions is just too embarrassing. ;-)

Comment: @Learning: I'd say it's more of an approximation. It would also match invalid stuff like "blabla)(bla(XYZ)bla". If this can happen depends on the OP's situation, of course.

Answer (score 2):

for sql server

```
declare @x  varchar(100)

set @X= 'fgjfkfgkjz(12345)'
set @X= '()'
set @X= '(1234)'
set @X= 'fgjfkfgkjz()dfddf'
set @X= 'fgjfkfgkjz(123)dfddf'

PRINT '>>'+SUBSTRING(@x,CHARINDEX('(',@x)+1,CHARINDEX(')',@x)-(CHARINDEX('(',@x))-1)+'<<'
```

update command:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn=SUBSTRING(YourColumn,CHARINDEX('(',YourColumn)+1,CHARINDEX(')',YourColumn)-(CHARINDEX('(',YourColumn))-1)
    WHERE xxx=yyy
```